# Different types of drivers - Automation

Tags: selenium, automation, native, appium, pageobjects

There is different types of driver for automation

I am automating iOS native app using appium and Selenium.

Which driver I should use from following list:

1. WebDriver
2. RemoteWebDriver
3. IOSDriver
4. AppiumDriver

I am going to use PageObject Pattern for that.

If anyone have Sample Project with PageObject pattern for iOS native app(Appium+Selenium).

Please help.

Comment: Sample project with [Selenium and Page Object Pattern](http://automatetheplanet.com/advanced-page-object-pattern/). As for the which driver you should choose, what does your research of them suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppiumDriver or IOSDriver.

1. Build application via XCode on real device
2. Then run [Appium](http://appium.io/) (you can download UI app for Mac)
3. setCapailities in BeforeMethod, you also will need to specify device udid

Try this if you doing it on real device:

```
   @BeforeMethod
   public void setup(){

   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.1");
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone");
   capabilities.setCapability("udid", "your_ud_id_number");
   driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things clear

`WebDriver` is an interface

`RemoteWebDriver` is a generic implementation of `WebDriver` in selenium

`AppiumDriver` is an abstract class from Appium Javaclient which extends `RemoteWebDriver`[not directly though]

`IOSDriver` is an implementation that extends `AppiumDriver`

as your test focuses on iOS Native app go with `IOSDriver` so that you'll get all the methods implemented by appium for IOS.

And as the name suggests PageObject is a *pattern* You have to implement as per the behaviour and content of the page.You can see references [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) and [here](http://automatetheplanet.com/advanced-page-object-pattern/)

Comment: Very useful. Thanks Madhan. Do you have any sample project which has used appiumDriver or IOSDriver and followed PageObject Pattern?